# Castle Windsor StartableFacility does not start

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, castle-windsor

I was following the example (Aggressive old mode) given in:

http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Startable-Facility&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Here is my full source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Castle.Facilities.Startable;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;

namespace Test
{
    public interface IStartable
    {
        void Start();
        void Stop();
    }

    public class Startable : IStartable
    {
        public Startable()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created!");
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started!");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped!");
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class StartableFacilityContainerTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void TestOperation()
        {
            IKernel container = new DefaultKernel();

            container.AddFacility<StartableFacility>();

            container.Register(Component.For<Startable>());
            Console.WriteLine("Registered!");

            container.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Released!");
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run it, I get:

```
Registered!
Released!
```

when I expect to get (as given in the example):

```
Created!
Started!
Registered!
Stopped!
Released!
```

Basically my Startable did not start.

This is tested in .Net 4.0 and Castle Windsor 3.0

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
container.Register(Component.For<Startable>()
     .StartUsingMethod(s => s.Start)
     .StopUsingMethod(s => s.Stop);
```

Comment: Cheers. Seems like the old mode is not supported any more.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Installers. This helped me:

```
container.AddFacility<StartableFacility>(f => f.DeferredTryStart());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have created and implemented your own `IStartable` interface instead of just implementing the `Castle.Core.IStartable`